# Gnuplot problem about plotting band under pdf terminal

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Here is my data file named "DATA":

```
1   10  20  15  25
2   20  30  25  35
3   30  40  35  45
4   40  50  45  55
```

Here is my code:

```
set term pdf enh solid color
set style fill transparent solid 0.3 noborder

datafile = "DATA"

set output "Output.pdf"

set xrange [1:4]
set yrange [0:60]

set xtics format "%.1f" 
set ytics format "%.0f"

plot 'DATA' using 1:2:3 notitle w filledcurves lc "purple", \
     'DATA' using 1:4:5 notitle w filledcurves lc "purple"
```

And then here's the problem. Although I have set both bands' color to be "purple", they still show a different color deeper than purple where two bands overlap. Just as the picture showed: [Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj6mt.png). And that is what I don't want. I want an additive band with one uniform color.

But if I simply change the terminal from pdf to post or whatever, I won't get an image with transparent lines.(I will plot other things in the picture since the codes above is a simplified one.) Because it seems post terminal doesn't support transparency.

So can I have a suggestion to this problem? Thanks a million!!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You want an additive band? Then set it `solid 1.0`.Ok, but you want it transparent? So, then you basically want a fill between column 2 and column 5 or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I want the band to be both additive and transparent. But not just a fill between column 2 and column 5. The data I listed here are just simplified. I can certainly give you  another DATA file:    1 10 20 0 10
2 20 30 15 25
3 30 40 30 40
4 40 50 45 55    . Only column 4 and column 5 have been changed. But this kind of band can not be included in one filled curve code, but I want the band's color to be unified. That is my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works in your second case, but probably not in general. Depending on the numbers you might have to calculate the intersection points of your bands which will be some extra effort.
And maybe there is a smarter way to find the minimum and maximum of 4 numbers.
Check the two versions in comparison.

**Code:**

```
### plot transparent additive bands
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 10 20  0 10
2 20 30 15 25
3 30 40 30 40
4 40 50 45 55
EOD

Min4(a,b,c,d) = a<=b && a<=c && a<=d ? a : b<=c && b<=d ? b : c<=d ?  c : d
Max4(a,b,c,d) = a>=b && a>=c && a>=d ? a : b>=c && b>=d ? b : c>=d ?  c : d

set style fill transparent solid 0.3 noborder
unset key

set multiplot layout 1,2
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 w filledcurves lc "purple", \
            '' u 1:4:5 w filledcurves lc "purple"

    plot $Data u 1:(Min4($2,$3,$4,$5)):(Max4($2,$3,$4,$5)) w filledcurves lc "purple"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Flush Glad to hear that this helped! However, I guess covering the general case of addition of two arbitrary bands will be a bit more complex. I will think about it.

Comment: Just maybe the max and min code can be modified like: `Min(a,b,c,d) = a<=b && a<=c && a<=d ? a : b<=c && b<=d ? b : c<=d ?  c : d`.

Comment: @Flush right, this is too much code ;-) . I will modifiy the answer. Thanks for the hint.